# TypeError null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSplashScreen.default.hide')

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

I am using React-Native, Android Studio and windows10.
I got error. null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeSplashScreen.default.hide')
Almost all of the answer methods were implemented, but they were not.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVo0y.png)

My Code

App.js partial

```
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen'

export default class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        // do stuff while splash screen is shown
        // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
        setTimeout(() => {
              SplashScreen.hide();
          }, 1000);
    }
```

MainApplication.java partial

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreenReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;  // 추가
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
           return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new SvgPackage(),
            new SplashScreenReactPackage()  //here
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }
```

MainActivity.java partial

```
import android.os.Bundle; // 추가
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; // 추가

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  /**
   * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
   * rendering of the component.
   */
  @Override  // 추가
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { // 추가
    SplashScreen.show(this);  // 추가
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // 추가
  } // 추가
```

launch_screen.xml partial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash_logo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```